# 3.3V DAC output to 50V amplification

Tags: amplifier, high-voltage, dac

I have DAC 3.3V generated narrow square pulses that I need to amplify to 50Vdc. For this purpose an OPA551 single supply opamp works fine, but it's quiescent current of ~7mA @ 50V consumes too much power.

I hoped to use a LT1013 at 44V (trade off) and 0.5mA Iq, but it seems to only swing to the negative rail.

Because high voltage single supply opamps are hard to find and expensive, 
should I go with a transistor or FET amp circuit to amplify the 3.3V pulses? Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Or any other design ideas?

Update: Some more details on the circuit as requested. It is battery powered, the 50V is generated by a DC-DC converter, is stable and works ok with the OPA551. The pulse frequency is 1kHz and are 50µS wide and the required output current doesn't exceed 10-15mA. The OPA551 was a good fit besides the current consumption. That is to say I want to preserve as much power as possible because of the battery operation.

And indeed the LT1013 as a low power amp also had problems with the slew rate.

Comment: You're working with 50V swings, but 7mA is too much current from the amp?  50V: but what is the load? Across what kind of impedance does 50V have to be produced?

Comment: What accuracy is the DAC?  Actually, what accuracy do you need for the 50V output?  What frequency are the pulses at?  Watch out for slew-rate limitations in low current opamps.

Comment: ... How wide are the pulses? What kind of fidelity do you expect at the output? Most importantly, what would you consider to be a reasonable power budget in this application?

Comment: Also, don't think that you absolutely use an op amp whose data sheet says that it's for single supply operation. Any op-amp can be used on single supply, with the appropriate care, like generating a stable V/2 reference that tries to preserve a good PSRR.  I think that the key difference in an amp which is "for single supply use" is that its common mode range behaves well near, or at, the negative rail. A dual supply amp that can only go within 2V of the negative rail will cause difficulties in some single supply uses, obviously.

Comment: I'm presuming you have a power supply that is between 54V and 60V - what are the losses in generating it - is it regulated - what are the losses in the regulator? If it isn't regulated you are in danger of either not producing 50Vpk or exceeding the OP551 max rails with ac supply variations

Comment: What are acceptable rise and fall times?(say, measured at the 10% and 90% voltages)

Comment: If you're not going to provide the requested details -- *all of them* -- then the question will have to be closed as "not a real question".

Comment: Regarding the questions about accuracy, rise and fall times, DAC, i don't think these are critical for the application. That is to say, some distortion is allowed. @DaveTweed this is my first post here. Do I provide enough details?

Comment: No, not yet. For example, you are using a "DAC" to generate the pulses, which implies that you want to have some control over their amplitude. How accurate does that need to be? And if the other parameters are not critical to you, you need to state that, giving some numbers. Would it be OK if the risetime on a 50 us pulse was 20-30 us? Would it be OK to use a low-voltage amplifier driving a transformer to increase the output voltage?

Comment: Ok, I see, didn't think about those 'extremes'. The pulses generated need to have a rise and fall time within a few µs. They need to be rather sharp needles with a 1:20 duty-cycle and a varying amplitude from 0 to 50V. Because of these requirements a transformer wouldn't be a solution for this application. Hope this clarifies it a bit more!

Comment: Are you interested in controlling the voltage of the pulse?  If so, how precise do you need to be?  If not, if you just want to swing the full supply voltage, that's a much easier spec to meet.

Comment: Yes, the DAC generates pulses of varying voltage.

Comment: Again, how accurate does the voltage need to be?  How many bits is your DAC?

Comment: 7 bits, so fairly coarse resolution, but is sufficient. Can you elaborate on why this is important?

Comment: Precision affects the design of the rest of the system.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to have a continuous analog signal to represent the peak voltage, and a separate digital signal to trigger the pulses?

Comment: The circuit is multiplexing a series of actuators that are voltage controlled (hence the DAC generated pulses). So am generating a pulse train where the actuators are switched in time.

Comment: Can the operating load be isolated from ground, i.e. not connected to the generating circuit's ground reference in any way? Or does it need to be referenced to the same ground, directly or indirectly?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Load can be isolated as long as I get the desired potential difference.

Comment: What's the battery voltage?

Comment: 3V Lithium cell.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so you basically need an audio amplifier circuit but without the high-power stage.  So here's a op-amp + Sziklai output stage amplifier that should supply 50V swing at low currents.

[image]

It simulated OK in my head, but I tried it in LTspice to get the supply current and transient response, and tune the feedback for stability.

[image]

Blue trace is 3V supply current, and red is 50V supply current.  The other two are input and output.

You could save some quiescent current by using a 1.5 V supply for the emitter voltage instead of the 40k+40k divider.  20k to a normal rail-splitter circuit would work.

Comment: This looks like a good solution. I will give it a try. Are the transistors and opamp critical as I don't have these laying around. Thanks for your extensive feedback!

Comment: There's nothing very special about those transistors but they have a high Vceo.  Many general-purpose transistors are usually only rated for 40 volts or so.  You'll need more than 50, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Since you only want to make bigger pulses, not arbitrary waveforms, you don't need a general purpose amplifier anyway.  All you need is the ability to control a high side switch, and maybe a low side switch depending on what the output drive requirements are.

A PFET with a pullup resistor on the gate, zener to limit the gate voltage, and a low side switchable current drive can turn the FET on and off with no quiescient current at all when off.

Above is a basic topology that works.  If you need faster turn-off time than a pullup provides, you can add a PNP clamp that is turned on for a µs or so when trying to turn off the FET.  You may also need a low side driver versus a simple passive pulldown on the output depending on what the sink current requirement is.  You said 15 mA, but we don't know if that is only for sourcing or also for sinking.

Comment: Have been thinking about the high side PFET solution, but couldn't picture in my mind how to control it exactly. Do you have a concrete schematic example at hand? This is my first post here and am impressed by the high level of feedback I get here!

Comment: To add to my above comment: I only need sourcing, not sinking.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got around fixing the quiescent current problem. I slapped my forehead not thinking about it before, but the answer is simply to make use of the quite extreme 1:20 duty-cycle of my application. Dynamically switching the op-amp on/off when needed reduces current consumption accordingly. I also found the OPA454 op-amp with a much better I<sub>q</sub> and has an enable option which made interfacing to my 3.3V logic simple.